# Can the reduced state of a mixed entangled state be pure?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

For an entangled pure state, the Schmidt decomposition is such that there are at least two non-zero Schmidt coefficients. Tracing out one subsystem implies that the other subsystem is mixed.

Explicitly, we have

$$\psi = \sum_k\sqrt{\lambda_k}\vert k\rangle_A \vert k\rangle_B$$

$$\rho = \vert\psi\rangle\langle\psi\vert = \sum_{k,k'}\sqrt{\lambda_k}\sqrt\lambda_{k'}\vert k\rangle_A \vert k\rangle_B\langle k\vert_A\langle k'\vert_B$$

Taking the partial trace gives us a sum of the form below with at least two nonzero terms.
$$\rho_A = \sum_k \lambda_k \vert k\rangle\langle k\vert$$

This is a diagonal matrix with rank 2 or more and is hence a mixed state.

Is there a similar argument one can make for the case where $\rho$ is a mixed entangled state? Alternatively, if this is not true, can one provide a counter example for which the reduced state is pure but the state $\rho$ is still entangled?

Comment: What do you mean by "similar argument"?

Comment: @Norbert Schuch I mean an argument that proves that the reduced state of a mixed entangled state is always mixed.

Comment: But this doesn't teach us anything: The reduced state of a non-entangled mixed states will also be mixed (with few exceptions).

Comment: @NorbertSchuch yes, that's true. But I was wondering if either one can prove the statement that all entangled mixed states have reduced states that are mixed or find a counterexample of an entangled mixed state with a reduced state that is pure.

Comment: Then, PLEASE, ask that CLEARLY in your question!  --  Other than that, the statement is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A mixed entangled state is a mixture of pure entangled states,
$$
\rho = \sum p_i |\psi_i\rangle\langle \psi_i|
$$
with (at least some) $|\psi_i\rangle$ entangled.  We then have
$$
\rho_A = \mathrm{tr}_B \rho = \sum p_i \rho^A_i\ ,
$$
with $\rho^A_i = \mathrm{tr}_B |\psi_i\rangle\langle \psi_i|$.  Since at least one $|\psi_i\rangle$ is entangled, at least one $\rho^A_i$ has $\mathrm{rank}(\rho^A_i)\ge 2$.  Since all $\rho^A_i\ge0$, we have that
$$
\mathrm{rank}(\sum p_i\rho^A_i)\ge \mathrm{max}(\mathrm{rank}(\rho^A_i))\ge 2\ .
$$

Thus, for any entangled mixed state, the reduced state $\rho_A$ is mixed as well.  (Note, however, that the same is true for almost all separable mixed states as well.)